# How to refuse Apache Tomcat login page?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

I need to get access to my own home page that I created with Spring Boot. I created a simple controller that returns the HTML page

```java
@Controller
public class HomePage{
    public String home(){
        return "home";
    }
}
```

The home.html is located in `resources/templates/`.

After I execute the project and get to the `localhost:8080`, the following page appeared:

[image]

logs:

```java
Using generated security password: a4752144-65d7-456c-b250-97e58d4fffcd

This generated password is for development use only. Your security configuration must be updated before running your application in production.

2022-08-29 15:19:17.389  INFO 19260 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@2adce412, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@629cf53c, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@1fc386f8, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@d7c4fcb, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@72d7afff, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@2cd31214, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@5857d723, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter@78ab63b5, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter@6d84ab90, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@362fd4e9, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@3777fc44, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@79454d8e, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@3182143c, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@498503cb, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@6d38a81d, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@294bb6ae] 2022-08-29 15:19:17.543  INFO 19260 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path '' 2022-08-29 15:19:17.553  INFO 19260
--- [           main] com...Application  : Started DeardiaryApplication in 8.385 seconds (JVM running for 9.464)
```

First of all - I can't use the provided password: neither `admin` nor `root` username does not match this password and I receive bad credentials error, I also tried admin-tomcat, both-tomcat username-password pairs as I found in the tutorials, but nothing do not match.

**But the main issue is that I, of course,  do not need to use any password for access to my own page**. Early I developed some projects, using spring-boot, and I don't remember I faced such problems. I do not install any tomcat servers by the handle, I just include them in my project via build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.3'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.13.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.hltr'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5'
    implementation group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.30'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

So, how to avoid the Apache Tomcat login page and get access to my project?

Comment: THat isn't the tomcat login page... What do you think `spring-boot-starter-security` is for....

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll look in this side

Comment: Default username is `user`. Please read the docs on how to customise spring security or just remove the dependency of you don’t need security in your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not default Apache login page. It is default login page of Spring Security (basic authentication).

Focus at

```
Using generated security password: a4752144-65d7-456c-b250-97e58d4fffcd
```

Login by username: `admin`
password: `a4752144-65d7-456c-b250-97e58d4fffcd` (this is an UUID version 4 string)

If you don't want to see this page, remove dependency of Spring Security by removing this line

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
```

If you want set default username and password pair (account) by your choice, inside file `application.properties`, add content like this

```java
spring.security.user.name=valentyn_hruzytskyi
spring.security.user.password=MyScrET42
```